# flow layout in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I'm new in GWT.

I have tab panel and vertical-panel in it (as a tab). I want that vertical panel fills all size of the tab panel. But now it(vPanel) is just a small rectangle in the TabLayoutPanel (in the left top corner).

Is there, in GWT, anything that looks like FlowLayout in Swing?

There SplitLayoutPanel has TabLayoutPanel and TabLayoutPanel has VPanel. And this vPanel is displaying as a rectangle in top-left corner.

There a code I use for now:

```
 TabLayoutPanel rightTabLayoutPanel = new TabLayoutPanel(1.5, Style.Unit.EM);

 VerticalPanel vPanel1 = new VerticalPanel();
 rightTabLayoutPanel.add(vPanel1, "Russian");

 SplitLayoutPanel layoutPanel = new SplitLayoutPanel();
 layoutPanel.setSize("900px", "400px");
 layoutPanel.add(rightTabLayoutPanel);
```

I want vPanel fills full size, and when i change the size of split-panel vPanel would react and change its size too.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vPanel will grow if you add any widgets to it.
Check out FlowPanel in GWT if you want FlowLayout kind of container.

Comment: maybe i was not very correct in my explanation. i fixed the code. There SplitLayoutPanel has TabLayoutPanel and TabLayoutPanel has VPanel. And this vPanel is displaying as a rectangle in top-left corner.

Comment: You can try setting the width of the vPanel to 100%. But my original comment still holds. If your vPanel does not contain any child widgets, why are you concerned about it filling the parent?